# Comparing numpy array with itself by element efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I am performing a large number of these calculations:

`A == A[np.newaxis].T`

where A is a dense numpy array which frequently has common values.

For benchmarking purposes we can use:

```
n = 30000
A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)
A == A[np.newaxis].T
```

When I perform this calculation, I run into memory issues. I believe this is because the output isn't in more efficient bitarray or np.packedbits format. A secondary concern is we are performing twice as many comparisons as necessary, since the resulting Boolean array is symmetric.

The questions I have are:

1. Is it possible to produce the Boolean numpy array output in a more memory efficient fashion without sacrificing speed? The options I know about are bitarray and np.packedbits, but I only know how to apply these after the large Boolean array is created.
2. Can we utilise the symmetry of our calculation to halve the number of comparisons processed, again without sacrificing speed?

I will need to be able to perform & and | operations on Boolean arrays output. I have tried bitarray, which is super-fast for these bitwise operations. But it is slow to pack np.ndarray -> bitarray and then unpack bitarray -> np.ndarray.

[Edited to provide clarification.]

Comment: `x == x[:, None]` also seems to do what you want.

Comment: your output should be ridiculously sparse, so I'd say you want to save the indices of the`True` values rather than some homebrewed `packbits` implementation

Comment: You can `argsort` and compare consecutive elements. That is O(n log n) time and O(n) space. compared to O(n^2) and O(n^2) for the direct approach.

Comment: @DanielF, is it possible / efficient to perform Boolean operations on sparse matrices? I've tried using & and | operations, but these don't seem to be implemented.

Comment: You want to be able to do `and` and `or` operations on two 30k by 30k boolean matrices?  Or do you want to broadcast them somehow?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, this seems like a good idea. We can apply a [presumably highly optimized] sorting algorithm. Then just compare to adjacent elements. Would you be able to provide some code to show how you might implement this in numpy?

Comment: @DanielF, I may have several n x n Boolean arrays as a result of the above calculation. Then I will be performing & and | operations on those arrays. Numpy Boolean array and bitarray seem to be very efficient with this operations, from my testing.

Comment: @DanielF, I then use the resulting Boolean arrays (from applying & / | operations) in a series of other matrix / array calculations depending on some other parameters. I wanted to focus the discussion on this particular calculation, as these arrays will have a number of uses.

Comment: DanielF / PaulPanzer, thanks for your answers. Haven't ignored them (and, indeed, will return on them), but would you know a way, given 2 csr sparse Boolean n x n matrices (A, B), to compute: A & ~B. A & B is very easy/efficient via A.multiply(B) but I haven't found a way to compute A.multiply(~B).

Comment: What exactly is the output that you are expecting for this problem? A regular NumPy boolean array or some scipy sparse matrix?

Comment: @Divakar, I started with Boolean numpy array output. But both DanielF and PaulPanzer's answers below have me leaning towards using coordinates (or sparse).

Hence my question above on whether it's possible to calculate A.multiply(~B) for csr matrices A, B. If this is possible, then csr_sparse may be the way to go. The use of the Boolean output matrices are numerous (slicing by row or col, & vs others, | vs others, etc).

Comment: in set space, `a&~b` is implemented as `a-b`.  Similarly, with `csr` matrices you could do `A.multiply(A - B)`

Comment: Or A-(A.multiply(B)). Might be marginally cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one with `numba` to give us a NumPy boolean array as output -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba_app1(idx, n, s, out):
    for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:]):
        s0 = s[i:j]
        c = 0
        for p1 in s0[c:]:
            for p2 in s0[c+1:]:
                out[p1,p2] = 1
                out[p2,p1] = 1
            c += 1
    return out

def app1(A):
    s = A.argsort()
    b = A[s]
    n = len(A)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,b[1:] != b[:-1],True])
    out = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=bool)
    numba_app1(idx, n, s, out)
    out.ravel()[::out.shape[1]+1] = 1
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [287]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: n = 30000
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)

# Original soln
In [288]: %timeit A == A[np.newaxis].T
1 loop, best of 3: 317 ms per loop

# @Daniel F's soln-1 that skips assigning lower diagonal in output
In [289]: %timeit sparse_outer_eq(A)
1 loop, best of 3: 450 ms per loop

# @Daniel F's soln-2 (complete one)
In [291]: %timeit sparse_outer_eq(A)
1 loop, best of 3: 634 ms per loop

# Solution from this post
In [292]: %timeit app1(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 66.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Huh, not sure why your timings are so different than mine.  I do the same thing and get ~800ms for the broadcasted method and ~500ms for my sparse app.

Comment: @DanielF I am using your - `Alternatively, you can define sparse_outer_eq as: ` code. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I'm using the first one.

Comment: @DanielF Well that first one `sparse_outer_eq` doesn't look complete since that skips the lower diag ones. Do you have a complete solution?

Comment: Considering I don't know what the asker wants to do between generating the output and translating it to fancy indexing, I don't.  It is true that that method will need more postprocessing on the back end, but it will also make the bitwise math faster with the given .1% sparsity.

Comment: @DanielF Updated for `30K` elements.

Comment: In the end, I liked this solution because the resulting array can utilise all of numpy's "nice" features, e.g. ~A.

It would be great if sparse matrices were implemented generically enough so that default value can be non-zero.

Comment: That's not really the purpose of sparse matrices though.  The whole field of sparse algebra blows up if you allow non-zero defaults.  That's like saying booleans should allow "Maybe" - yeah a handful of fuzzy logic PhDs might like it, but the implementation would be a bear and for the other 99.99% of the population it would just be another error source to check for and slow everything down.

Comment: @DanielF Not sure I follow - What isn't the purpose of sparse matrices?

Comment: Non-zero defaults, as jp is wishing for.  I'm assuming he'd want `~A` to be a `sparse` matrix with `False` as the `A.data` and `True` as the default.  Sorry, should have used @

Comment: @DanielF, you are of course right. Whole branches of mathematics would break down for non-zero defaults. I was thinking more along the lines of: sparse matrices can be a subclass [with its special methods and applications] of a more generalized way of storing matrices via csr / coo / dok algorithms. In fact, I'm sure it's possible to subclass yourself and overwrite certain functionality for specific use cases.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't even a numpy answer, but should work to keep your data requirements down by using a bit of homebrewed sparse notation

```
from numba import jit

@jit   # because this is gonna be loopy
def sparse_outer_eq(A):
    n = A.size
    c = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if A[i] == A[j]:
                 c.append((i, j))
    return c
```

Now `c` is a list of coordinate tuples `(i, j)`, `i < j` that correspond to coordinates in your boolean array that are "True".  You can easily do `and` and `or` operations on these setwise:

```
list(set(c1) & set(c2))
list(set(c1) | set(c2))
```

Later, when you want to apply this mask to an array, you can back out the coordinates and use them for fancy indexing instead:

```
i_, j_ = list(np.array(c).T)
i = np.r_[i_, j_, np.arange(n)]
j = np.r_[j_, i_, np.arange(n)]
```

You can then `np.lexsort` `i` nd `j` if you care about order

Alternatively, you can define `sparse_outer_eq` as:

```
@jit
def sparse_outer_eq(A):
    n = A.size
    c = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if A[i] == A[j]:
                 c.append((i, j))
    return c
```

Which keeps >2x the data, but then the coordinates come out simply:

```
 i, j = list(np.array(c).T)
```

if you've done any `set` operations, this will still need to be `lexsort`ed if you want a rational order.

If your coordinates are each n-bit integers, this should be more space-efficient than boolean format as long as your sparsity is less than 1/n -> 3% or so for 32-bit.

as for time, thanks to `numba` it's even faster than broadcasting:

```
n = 3000
A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)

%timeit sparse_outer_eq(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.86 ms per loop

%timeit A == A[:, None]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop
```

and comparisons:

```
a = A == A[:, None]

b = B == B[:, None]

a_ = sparse_outer_eq(A)

b_ = sparse_outer_eq(B)

%timeit a & b
100 loops, best of 3: 5.9 ms per loop

%timeit list(set(a_) & set(b_))
1000 loops, best of 3: 641 µs per loop

%timeit a | b
100 loops, best of 3: 5.52 ms per loop

%timeit list(set(a_) | set(b_))
1000 loops, best of 3: 955 µs per loop
```

EDIT: if you want to do `&~` (as per your comment) use the second `sparse_outer_eq` method (so you don't have to keep track of the diagonal) and just do:

```
list(set(a_) - set(b_))
```

Comment: this is useful but a couple of issues:  
(1) Performance very sensitive to n and # of unique values, e.g. I see your method 3x slower for n = 15,000 and 200 unique values.  
(2) Operations such as ~A are not as easy. I would probably have to store a full set of all coordinates [or cycle through them all] and exclude items in set(a_). But cf https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1166.

Comment: Yeah, this method leans heavily on the fact that the original problem as stated is very sparse (1k unique values).  If your input and output matrices are relatively dense, a boolean matrix will be more performant.

Comment: However I will point out that even at 1bit/boolean, this method is more *memory* efficient than a boolean matrix as long as the sparsity is less than `1/log2(n)`, i.e 32 unique values for n<4e9 and 16 unique values for n<65k.  Of course, a non-operated `~` will blow any sort of sparsity up and make boolean more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the more or less canonical `argsort` solution:

```
import numpy as np

def f_argsort(A):
    idx = np.argsort(A)
    As = A[idx]
    ne_ = np.r_[True, As[:-1] != As[1:], True]
    bnds = np.flatnonzero(ne_)
    valid = np.diff(bnds) != 1
    return [idx[bnds[i]:bnds[i+1]] for i in np.flatnonzero(valid)]

n = 30000
A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)
groups = f_argsort(A)

for grp in groups:
    print(len(grp), set(A[grp]), end=' ')
print()
```

Comment: This is good, but like DanielF's solution, it doesn't easily allow computation / storage of ~A. To be fair, I should have made this clear in my original query. However, your canonical argsort function has been used also in Divakar's solution, which is the one I'm going for here.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis No worries, go for what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a solution to my question because it satisfies these 3 properties:

- Low, fixed, memory requirement
- Fast bitwise operations (&, |, ~, etc)
- Low storage, 1-bit per Boolean via packing integers

The downside is it is stored in np.packbits format. It is substantially slower than other methods (especially argsort), but if speed is not an issue the algorithm should work well. If anyone figures a way to optimise further, this would be very helpful.

**Update:** A more efficient version of the below algorithm can be found here: [Improving performance on comparison algorithm np.packbits(A==A[:, None], axis=1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48368855/9209546).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def bool2int(x):
    y = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(x):
        if j: y += int(j)<<(7-i)
    return y

@jit(nopython=True)
def compare_elementwise(arr, result, section):
    n = len(arr)

    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):

            section[col%8] = arr[row] == arr[col]

            if ((col + 1) % 8 == 0) or (col == (n-1)):
                result[row, col // 8] = bool2int(section)
                section[:] = 0

    return result

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
n = len(A)
result_arr = np.zeros((n, n // 8 if n % 8 == 0 else n // 8 + 1)).astype(np.uint8)
selection_arr = np.zeros(8).astype(np.uint8)

packed = compare_elementwise(A, result_arr, selection_arr)
```