# Improving performance on comparison algorithm np.packbits(A==A[:, None], axis=1)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, boolean

I am looking to memory optimise `np.packbits(A==A[:, None], axis=1)`, where `A` is dense array of integers of length `n`. `A==A[:, None]` is memory hungry for large `n` since the resulting Boolean array is stored inefficiently with each Boolean value costing 1 byte.

I wrote the below script to achieve the same result while packing bits one section at a time. It is, however, around 3x slower, so I am looking for ways to speed it up. Or, alternatively, a better algorithm with small memory overhead.

*Note*: this is a follow-up question to one I asked earlier; [Comparing numpy array with itself by element efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48279206/9209546).

Reproducible code below for benchmarking.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def bool2int(x):
    y = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(x):
        if j: y += int(j)<<(7-i)
    return y

@jit(nopython=True)
def compare_elementwise(arr, result, section):
    n = len(arr)
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):

            section[col%8] = arr[row] == arr[col]

            if ((col + 1) % 8 == 0) or (col == (n-1)):
                result[row, col // 8] = bool2int(section)
                section[:] = 0

    return result

n = 10000
A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n)

result_arr = np.zeros((n, n // 8 if n % 8 == 0 else n // 8 + 1)).astype(np.uint8)
selection_arr = np.zeros(8).astype(np.uint8)

# memory efficient version, but slow
packed = compare_elementwise(A, result_arr, selection_arr)

# memory inefficient version, but fast
packed2 = np.packbits(A == A[:, None], axis=1)

assert (packed == packed2).all()

%timeit compare_elementwise(A, result_arr, selection_arr)  # 1.6 seconds
%timeit np.packbits(A == A[:, None], axis=1)  # 0.460 second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution 3 times faster than the numpy one (a.size must be a multiple of 8; see below) :

```
@nb.njit
def comp(a):
    res=np.zeros((a.size,a.size//8),np.uint8)
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        for j,y in enumerate(a):
            if x==y: res[i,j//8] |= 128 >> j%8 
    return res
```

This works because the array is scanned one time, where you do it many times,
and amost all terms are null.

```
In [122]: %timeit np.packbits(A == A[:, None], axis=1)
389 ms ± 57.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [123]: %timeit comp(A)
123 ms ± 24.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If `a.size%8 > 0`, the cost for find back the information will be higher. The best way in this case is to pad the initial array with some (in `range(7)`) zeros.

For completeness, the padding could be done as so:

```
if A.size % 8 != 0: A = np.pad(A, (0, 8 - A.size % 8), 'constant', constant_values=0)
```